# How to save image source variable using php

Tags: php, html

Is it has method to save `<img src="XXXXX">` image path to database using PHP. Why src path doesn't pick in PHP . My PHP code is

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
if(!empty($_POST["submit1"]) || isset($_POST["submit1"])){
 if (isset($_POST['img1'])) {
        $filename1= $_POST['img1'];
    }
  if (isset($_POST['img2'])) {
        $filename2= $_POST['img2'];
    }
}
?>
```

And my html code is

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test 
    </title>
</head>
    <body>
     <form  action="phpscript/test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>Images </div> 
              <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
              <div class="row align-text-center">                                     
                    <div class="col-sm2">
                        
 <input type="image"  id="img1" name="img1"  src="img/1.jpg" width="150" height="150"  style="border: "/> 
    
                    </div>
     <div class="col-sm2">
    <input type="image" src="img/2.jpg" width="150" height="150" id="img2" name="img2" style="border: " /> 
                                             
                    </div>
                  <div class="col-sm2">
    <button class="btn " type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1">Submit</button>  
    </form>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Actually I need to pick image path in php code.But in php code `$filename1` and `$filename2` values are NULL.Is it another method to get image path in php code?

Comment: Did you already use `var_dump($_FILES);` to see, what variables it has?

Comment: Why should any `$_FILES['img1']` exist? Your form field with that name is _not_ a file upload field, it is just a `type="image"` field. Those do not send any file names.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what the element `type="image"`does. The `src`-attribute is for how the element should look, it won't be submitted with the form

Comment: `$_POST['img1']` also wouldn't be the file, take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: I change code  $_FILES to $_POST.But it also doesn't work.I think<input type="image" src="XXX">  doesn't     work as input on POST method.

Comment: In my sample code first  show image in <input type="image" src="XXX"> tag on web page.after that use submit button to save the data.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misconception about `<input type="image">` this. This just defines a image as a submit button. Check out this as a reference https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_image.asp
Now to save image path in a PHP variable, you have to select that image as a file.

```
<input type="image"  id="img1" name="img1"  src="img/1.jpg" width="150" height="150"  style="border:"/>
<input type="image" src="img/2.jpg" width="150" height="150" id="img2" name="img2" style="border:" />
```

This just makes an output of images which are `img/1.jpg` and `img/2.jpg`.
To get images path in a PHP variable you have to change these line like bellow:

```
<input type="file" name="img1">
<input type="file" name="img2">
```

Then you can select an image file.
In PHP part change your code with this code:

```
<?php
    include('conn.php');
    if(!empty($_POST["submit1"]) || isset($_POST["submit1"])){
     if (isset($_FILES["img1"])) {
            $filename1= $_FILES["img1"]["name"];
        }
      if (isset($_FILES['img2'])) {
            $filename2= $_FILES["img2"]["name"];
        }
    }
?>
```

To know details about PHP file/image uploading check out this https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: can we use hidden input to use for this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do actually? If you just want to get the image path, you don't need any hidden input tag.